# Managing Button State and Resultant Processing with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've got some toggles that can be turned on/off. They get on/off state from a parent functional component. When a user toggles the state, I need to update the state in the parent and run a function.

That function uses the state of all the toggles to filter a list of items in state, which then changes the rendered drawing in a graph visualization component.

Currently, they toggle just fine, but the render gets out of sync with the state of the buttons, because the processing function ends up reading in old state.

I tried using useEffect(), but because the function has a lot of dependencies it causes a loop.

I tried coupling useRef() with useState() in a custom hook to read out the current state of at least the newest filter group that was set, but no luck there either.

Any suggestions on how I could restructure my code in a better way altogether, or a potential solution to this current problem?

Gross function that does the filtering:

```
function filterItems(threshold, items = {}) {
    const { values } = kCoreResult;
    const { coloredItems } = rgRef.current;

    let itemsForUse;
    let filteredItems;

    if (Object.entries(items).length === 0 && items.constructor === Object) {
      itemsForUse = baseItemsRef.current;
    } else {
      itemsForUse = items;
    }

    const isWithinThreshold = id => has(values, id) && values[id] >= threshold;

    // filter for nodes meeting the kCoreValue criterion plus all links
    filteredItems = pickBy(
      itemsForUse,
      (item, id) => !isNode(item) || isWithinThreshold(id)
    );
    filteredItems = pickBy(
      filteredItems,
      item =>
        !has(item, 'data.icon_type') || !filterRef.current[item.data.icon_type]
    );

    setRg(rg => {
      rg.filteredItems = leftMerge(filteredItems, coloredItems);

      return {
        ...rg,
      };
    });

    setMenuData(menuData => {
      menuData.threshold = threshold;

      return {
        ...menuData,
      };
    });
  }
```

Function that calls it after button is pressed that also updates button state (button state is passed down from the filter object):

```
function changeCheckBox(id, checked) {
    setFilter(filter => {
      filter[id] = !checked;

      return {
        ...filter,
      };
    });

    filterItems(menuData.threshold);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems calling your `filterItems` function *in* the handler is causing the stale state bug, the state update hasn't been reconciled yet. Separate out your functions that update state and "listen" for updates *to* state to run the filter function.

Here's a demo that should help see the pattern:

```
export default function App() {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState(filterOptions);

  const onChangeHandler = e => {
    setFilters({ ...filters, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked });
  };

  const filterItems = (threshold, items = {}) => {
    console.log("Gross function that does the filtering");
    console.log("threshold", threshold);
    console.log("items", items);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    filterItems(42, filters);
  }, [filters]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      {Object.entries(filters).map(([filter, checked]) => {
        return (
          <Fragment key={filter}>
            <label htmlFor={filter}>{filter}</label>
            <input
              id={filter}
              name={filter}
              type="checkbox"
              checked={checked}
              onChange={onChangeHandler}
            />
          </Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit withered-meadow-qwzmj]

This works by de-coupling state updates from state side-effects. The handler updates the filters state by always returning a new object with next filter values, and the effect hook triggers on value changes to `filters`.

Comment: Hey there, this makes a lot of sense, thanks a ton for helping out. In this example, if threshold was also a piece of state, like: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-hertz-8ytyk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

How would I remedy the "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'filterItems'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)" issue? As if I do add threshold into the dependency array, when it is changed, my app will run this function when it shouldn't be.

Comment: Updated my sandbox with a `threshold` that updates.

Comment: Ahh yes, so in the updated sandbox, when we set a new threshold the "Gross function that does the filtering" runs again, which I believe is the last piece of the puzzle I'm looking to solve. I'd like to find an option where the same exact thing is achieved, but the function only runs when filter changes, and not other state like threshold that are in the function.

Comment: Can you share under what conditions the filter function should be called?

Comment: For sure, so in this example, if there was a way to make the function only run when filter is changed, even though it uses threshold state, that would completely solve my problem.

Comment: You can specify as many of the dependencies as you wish/feel is necessary. For example, specifying an empty dependency array is analogous to the `componentDidMount` lifecycle function. If you don't want the effect to run when `threshold` updates then don't include it in the dependency array. It's likely being flagged by your linter so you can disable that rule for that line specifically, `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`. I updated my sandbox with example.

Comment: I guess I tend to keep my effects "pure" in the sense that for the same input I get the same output but I'm unable to find that recommendation in the react docs.